# Why is code work on JSfiddle but didn't on my PC?(scrolling)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanna to do scroll down to next div by pressing button on pure JS. But this code:

```js
var hiddenElement = document.getElementById("box");
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');

function handleButtonClick() {
   hiddenElement.scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"});
}

btn.addEventListener('click', handleButtonClick);
```

```css
.big {
   background: #ccc;
   height:100vh;
}

.btn {
   font-size: 14px;
}

.box {
   background: lightgreen;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     <button type="button" class="btn">Press</button>
    <div class="big"></div>
    <div id="box" class="box">Hidden Block</div>
</body>
</html>
```

didn't work when i opened it on my PC BUT it is working on JSfiddle. Why? 
Here is the link: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/careCaban/7urga5hk/8/)

Comment: jsFiddle wraps the script into onload function. You're executing this script before the body is parsed, the script can't find elements which don't exist yet.

Comment: thanks. How can i fix this?

Comment: Easiest... put your script before closing `</body>`, or [read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event), for jQuery [read that](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).